# ggplot2 v2.21.9 sec.axis in polar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to add a secondary axis using the recently introduced function `sec.axis` in `ggplot2`. This function works well with scatter/bar plots, but not for polar plot: In the following code, the name for the second y-axis appears, but not the axis.

Is there any workaround or option, that I have not figured out?

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(40);
Location <- data.frame(Winkel = round(runif(1000, 0, 24), 0))
Location$BAD <- Location$Winkel %in% c(seq(7, 18))
Abschnitte <- c(0:24)

polar <- data.frame(Winkel2 = c(1.5, 2.34, 1.2, 3.45, 1.67, 2.61, 1.11, 13.2), 
                    value = c(0.1, 0.03, 0.02, 0.015, 0.01, 0.04, 0.09, 0.06))

ggplot(Location, aes(x = Winkel, fill = BAD, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0,24), colour = "black") + 
  coord_polar(start = 0) + theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = 3) +
  ylab("Percentual allocation time") + 
  ggtitle("") +
  scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = Abschnitte, labels = Abschnitte) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
           sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*5, name = "mean direction")) +
  geom_segment(data = polar, aes(x = Winkel2, y = 0, xend = Winkel2, yend = value, fill = NA), 
               arrow = arrow(angle = 30, type = "closed", length = unit(0.3, "cm")))
```

[image]

Comment: To me this seems like a bug. I posted [an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2072).

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for it to be solved then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @henrik mentioned in the comments, this is a bug. It's [been patched](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2188) and is available if you use the development version from GitHub (i.e., `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`).

Here's the example after the patch:

```r
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
set.seed(40);
Location <- data.frame(Winkel = round(runif(1000, 0, 24), 0))
Location$BAD <- Location$Winkel %in% c(seq(7, 18))
Abschnitte <- c(0:24)

polar <- data.frame(Winkel2 = c(1.5, 2.34, 1.2, 3.45, 1.67, 2.61, 1.11, 13.2), 
                    value = c(0.1, 0.03, 0.02, 0.015, 0.01, 0.04, 0.09, 0.06))

ggplot(Location, aes(x = Winkel, fill = BAD, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0,24), colour = "black") + 
  coord_polar(start = 0) + theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = 3) +
  ylab("Percentual allocation time") + 
  ggtitle("") +
  scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = Abschnitte, labels = Abschnitte) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
           sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*5, name = "mean direction")) +
  geom_segment(data = polar, aes(x = Winkel2, y = 0, xend = Winkel2, yend = value, fill = NA), 
               arrow = arrow(angle = 30, type = "closed", length = unit(0.3, "cm")))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]